How to write a chat client without waiting for input?
This is my attempt at the loop for an extremely basic IRC client.
while True:                                                                                                           
    try:                                                                                                              
        resp = s.recv(1024)                                                                                           
    except BlockingIOError:                                                                                           
        pass                                                                                                          
    else:                                                                                                             
        text = resp.decode('utf-8')                                                                                   
        print('Received Message: '+text)                                                                              
        if text.startswith('PING'):                                                                                   
            msg = 'PONG ' + text.split()[1]                                                                           
            s.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))                                                                               
                                                                                                                      
    message = input('>')                                                                                              
    s.send(bytes(message, 'utf-8'))

Above, I set blocking to false.  I'm trying to figure out how to change it so that it doesn't wait for input to go through, but will continue to receive messages. I don't mind if the output looks something like:
> Here's the start of my message
INCOMING MESSAGE RECEIVED
and here's the end of it.

as it's just a quick hack for a class. Any ideas on how to restructure my approach to this?

me personally solve this kind of problems with threading

The select module (and select.select() function call) is quite useful in this kind of situation; you can tell it to not return until at least one of a set of sockets has data ready-for-read, and then find out which socket(s) are ready after it returns and read from only them (which won't block).
